# How do I express generic map and set containers in Rust?

Tags: rust, generic-programming

I'm learning Rust coming from a C++ background and I'm writing a topological sort.

The input is a dependency map with type `Map<Key, Set<Key>>`, where every node (key) is mapped to its dependency (a set of keys). `Map` and `Set` can be any `Map` and `Set` implementation. The output is a vector with sorted topological order.

In C++, I would use a "template template parameter" for both `Map` and `Set`:

```cpp
template<
    class K,
    template<class...> class Map,
    template<class...> class Set
>
std::vector<K>
topological_sort(Map<K, Set<K>> const &depmap);
```

This function can apply to `map<Key, set<Key>>` or `unordered_map<Key, set<Key>>` or `map<Key, unordered_set<Key>>`, etc.

In Rust, it seems there is no "template template parameter". I can write the following:

```
fn topological_sort<K: Eq + Ord + Hash + Clone>(depmp: &BTreeMap<K, HashSet<K>>) -> Option<Vec<K>> {
}
```

But then the code isn't generic in terms of the container choice, since it won't work for `HashMap<K, HashSet<K>>`, etc.

I tried the hypothetical syntax:

```
fn topological_sort<Map, Set, K: Eq + Ord + Hash + Clone>(depmp: &Map::<K, Set::<K>>) -> Option<Vec<K>>
```

This does not work. What is Rust's solution for a generic container?

Comment: This feature is also known as _higher kinded types_, and Rust does not have it yet. Moreover, in Rust you can only access methods and associated types on generic type parameters that are provided by the trait bounds, in contrast to C++. There is no trait to describe a generic map in the Rust standard library, so you will have to define your own trait and use an assoicated type for the key type.

Comment: Take a look at iterator in Rust.

Comment: You can probably abstract the map type with something like `M: Index<K, Output=HashSet<K>>` but I don't think there's an equivalent for abstracting the set type.

Comment: Although you can probably write your own trait to abstract between `HashSet` and `BTreeSet`…

Comment: @SvenMarnach So I need to write `trait GenericSet<K>` and `trait GenericMap<K, V>`, then `impl<K> GenericSet<K> for HashSet<K>`, etc. That makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest I could come:

```
use std::collections::*;
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::ops::Index;

trait Set<K> {
    fn does_contain(&self, value: &K) -> bool;
}
impl<K: Eq + Hash> Set<K> for HashSet<K> {
    fn does_contain(&self, value: &K) -> bool {
        self.contains (value)
    }
}
impl<K: Eq + Ord> Set<K> for BTreeSet<K> {
    fn does_contain(&self, value: &K) -> bool {
        self.contains (value)
    }
}

fn topological_sort<K, S: Set<K>, M: Index<K, Output=S>> (depmp: &M) -> Option<Vec<K>> {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

It uses [`std::ops::Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Index.html) to abstract over the map type and a custom `Set` trait to abstract over the set type.

Answer (score 4):

> What is Rust's solution for a generic container?

The ideal solution for generic containers is not available *yet*. This would be covered by a feature currently in the implementation phase, [generic associated types (GATs)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md).

For the time being, there are ways to make your routines generic for certain use cases. In particular, it is common for a function to receiving an arbitrary sequence of data through a value that implements `IntoIterator`:

```
fn my_number_process<I>(stream: I) -> f32
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = f32>,
{
    stream.into_iter().map(|x| x * 2. + 5.).sum().unwrap_or(0.)
}
```

For dictionary-like containers, the [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) and [`IndexMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html) traits expose the specific functionality of obtaining a reference to a value in the receiver by a key with a known type. The methods in both cases return `&Self::Output`, leaving no room for recoverable errors or other kinds of outputs.
As an alternative, you can create a new trait that suits the purpose while attempting to overcome the lack of higher-kinded types. In particular, the trait below cannot be implemented for a plain `HashMap`:

```
trait IMap<K> {
    type Value;

    fn get<B: Borrow<K>>(&self, key: B) -> Option<Self::Value>;
}
```

This is because we cannot specify `Value` as a `&'a V` where `'a` is a lifetime that would be instantiated as the lifetime of `self`. However, it can be implemented for a reference to `HashMap`:

```
impl<'a, K, V> IMap<K> for &'a HashMap<K, V>
where
    K: Eq,
    K: Hash,
{
    type Value = &'a V;

    fn get<B: Borrow<K>>(&self, key: B) -> Option<Self::Value> {
        HashMap::get(self, key.borrow())
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=561e51ab9f0d7b06f67632c7fb6521bc)

A similar reasoning can be employed to a generic `Set` container.

Comment: Can all of this now be expressed with the newly stabilized GATs?