# Rust function that accepts either HashMap and BtreeMap

Tags: rust

```
fn edit_map_values(
            map1: &mut HashMap<String, i128> || &mut BTreeMap<String, i128>){
    for tuple in map1.iter_mut() {
        if !map1.contains_key(&"key1") {
             *tuple.1 += 1;
        }
    }
    map1.insert(&"key2", 10);
}
```

How do I write one function that accepts either HashMap and BtreeMap like in the example above?

Comment: The reason is I've two sets of String data one that needs to be sorted by key and the other does not and I want to perform the same operations on them. Also want to know if this is solvable to learn about Rust

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I express generic map and set containers in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595542/how-do-i-express-generic-map-and-set-containers-in-rust)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to abstract over types by using traits and for your specific use-case, you can take a look at this more constrained **example**.

```
use core::{borrow::Borrow, hash::Hash};
use std::collections::{BTreeMap, HashMap};

trait GenericMap<K, V> {
    fn contains_key<Q>(&self, k: &Q) -> bool
    where
        K: Borrow<Q>,
        Q: Hash + Eq + Ord;

    fn each_mut<F>(&mut self, cb: F)
    where
        F: FnMut((&K, &mut V));

    fn insert(&mut self, key: K, value: V) -> Option<V>;
}

impl<K, V> GenericMap<K, V> for HashMap<K, V>
where
    K: Eq + Hash,
{
    fn contains_key<Q>(&self, k: &Q) -> bool
    where
        K: Borrow<Q>,
        Q: Hash + Eq + Ord,
    {
        self.contains_key(k)
    }

    fn each_mut<F>(&mut self, mut cb: F)
    where
        F: FnMut((&K, &mut V)),
    {
        self.iter_mut().for_each(|x| cb(x))
    }

    fn insert(&mut self, key: K, value: V) -> Option<V> {
        self.insert(key, value)
    }
}

impl<K, V> GenericMap<K, V> for BTreeMap<K, V>
where
    K: Ord,
{
    fn contains_key<Q>(&self, k: &Q) -> bool
    where
        K: Borrow<Q>,
        Q: Hash + Eq + Ord,
    {
        self.contains_key(k)
    }

    fn each_mut<F>(&mut self, mut cb: F)
    where
        F: FnMut((&K, &mut V)),
    {
        self.iter_mut().for_each(|x| cb(x))
    }

    fn insert(&mut self, key: K, value: V) -> Option<V> {
        self.insert(key, value)
    }
}

fn edit_map_values<T: GenericMap<String, i128>>(map: &mut T) {
    map.each_mut(|(k, v)| {
        if k != "key1" {
            *v += 1;
        }
    });
    map.insert("key2".into(), 10);
}

fn main() {
    let mut hm: HashMap<String, i128> = [("One".into(), 1), ("Two".into(), 2)]
        .iter()
        .cloned()
        .collect();
    let mut btm: BTreeMap<String, i128> = [("Five".into(), 5), ("Six".into(), 6)]
        .iter()
        .cloned()
        .collect();
    dbg!(&hm);
    dbg!(&btm);
    edit_map_values(&mut hm);
    edit_map_values(&mut btm);
    dbg!(&hm);
    dbg!(&btm);
}
```

Comment: Maybe one could even condense the implementations via macros.

Comment: Excellent answer. Appreciate the high quality code. I wonder why there are not more traits used in the Rust std lib for common interfaces.

Comment: @phimuemue is it possible to have a macro that would duplicate the function and replace the type and add a unique function name?

Answer (score 2):

Way back before the 1.0 release, there used to be `Map` and `MutableMap` traits, but they have been removed before stabilization. The Rust type system is currently unable to express these traits in a nice way due to the lack of higher kinded types.

The [eclectic crate](https://github.com/apasel422/eclectic/) provides experimental collection traits, but they haven't been updated for a year, so I'm not sure they are still useful for recent versions of Rust.

Further information:

- [Does Rust have Collection traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159530/does-rust-have-collection-traits)
- [No common trait for Map types? (Rust language forum)](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/no-common-trait-for-map-types/8275)
- [Associated type constructors, part 1: basic concepts and introduction (blog post by Niko Matsakis)](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2016/11/02/associated-type-constructors-part-1-basic-concepts-and-introduction/)
- [Generic associated type RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md)

Comment: I can see how getting the right generality for traits is difficult. But a Map trait is something Rust should have. The interfaces of Btreemap and Hashmap are already the same

Comment: @Ben Actually, Rust does have a "Map" trait, except it's called [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Index.html)

Comment: @Jmb Index is not a good solution for this, because it does not allow you to check whether or not an element exists, nor to remove an element, nor to conditionally get an element.  You can not use Index for this without the possibility for panics (which can not always be caught, as panics may be implemented as aborts rather than unwinding).

Answer (score 0):

While there is no common `Map` trait, you could use a combination of other traits to operate on an Iterator to achieve similar functionality. Although this might not be very memory efficient due to cloning, and also a bit involved depending on the kind of operation you are trying to perform. The operation you tried to do may be implemented like this:

```
fn edit_map_values<I>(map: &mut I)
where
    I: Clone + IntoIterator<Item = (String, i128)> + std::iter::FromIterator<(String, i128)>,
{
    // Since into_iter consumes self, we have to clone here.
    let (keys, _values): (Vec<String>, Vec<_>) = map.clone().into_iter().unzip();

    *map = map
        .clone()
        .into_iter()
        // iterating while mutating entries can be done with map
        .map(|mut tuple| {
            if !keys.contains(&"key1".to_string()) {
                tuple.1 += 1;
            }
            tuple
        })
        // inserting an element can be done with chain and once
        .chain(std::iter::once(("key2".into(), 10)))
        .collect();
        // removing an element could be done with filter
        // removing and altering elements could be done with filter_map
        // etc.
}

fn main() {
    use std::collections::{BTreeMap, HashMap};

    {
        let mut m = HashMap::new();
        m.insert("a".to_string(), 0);
        m.insert("key3".to_string(), 1);

        edit_map_values(&mut m);

        println!("{:#?}", m);
    }

    {
        let mut m = BTreeMap::new();
        m.insert("a".to_string(), 0);
        m.insert("key3".to_string(), 1);

        edit_map_values(&mut m);

        println!("{:#?}", m);
    }
}
```

Both times the output is the same, except for the order of the HashMap of course:

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "key2": 10,
    "key3": 2,
}
```